# openSUSE - Install latest PHP from source

Tags: software-installation, package-management, apache-httpd, opensuse, php

I have PHP 7.2.5 and I need to upgrade to the latest PHP.

First I purged the old php by executing `apt-get purge php7`

Then I [downloaded php-7.3.7](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) extracted it to my webserver and executed `./configure && make && make install` and then restarted apache2 by executing `systemctl restart apache2`

This is what I get after executing `make install`:

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib64/extensions/debug-non-zts-20180731/
Installing PHP CLI binary:        /usr/local/bin/
Installing PHP CLI man page:      /usr/local/php/man/man1/
Installing phpdbg binary:         /usr/local/bin/
Installing phpdbg man page:       /usr/local/php/man/man1/
Installing PHP CGI binary:        /usr/local/bin/
Installing PHP CGI man page:      /usr/local/php/man/man1/
Installing build environment:     /usr/local/lib64/build/
Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
Installing helper programs:       /usr/local/bin/
  program: phpize
  program: php-config
Installing man pages:             /usr/local/php/man/man1/
  page: phpize.1
  page: php-config.1
Installing PEAR environment:      /usr/local/lib64/php/
[PEAR] Archive_Tar    - installed: 1.4.7
[PEAR] Console_Getopt - installed: 1.4.2
[PEAR] Structures_Graph- installed: 1.1.1
[PEAR] XML_Util       - installed: 1.4.3
[PEAR] PEAR           - installed: 1.10.9
Wrote PEAR system config file at: /usr/local/etc/pear.conf
You may want to add: /usr/local/lib64/php to your php.ini include_path
/srv/www/vhosts/xdebug/php-7.3.7/build/shtool install -c ext/phar/phar.phar /usr/local/bin
ln -s -f phar.phar /usr/local/bin/phar
```

If I execute my phpinfo.php, then it just downloads the file, because it can't interpret php...

Comment: I followed the instructions from this yt video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZpRdDd-zz4 and installed php normally with apt-get install and it installed php 7.2.5. Maybe this is the latest PHP for my server?

Comment: How does your web server interpret PHP?  If you are using `mod_php`, then you will also have to build that module for the new version of PHP you just built and tell Apache to use it instead.

Comment: Im not sure, how do I know?

Comment: Something in your Apache is serving PHP, either directly through `mod_php` or indirectly through a proxy.  The best way to find out would be to inspect your configuration.  If serving from `mod_php`, you need to build `mod_php` with your new version of PHP.  If serving from a proxy, you would need to make sure the PHP server Apache is proxying to is built with your new version of PHP.